# Error while importing Httpclient, httpcore & httpmime

Tags: android, android-studio, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am facing this problem in Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: httpclient is deprecated. you should use httpurlconnection instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your app's build.gradle file

```
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests you are not excluding the `META-INF/NOTICE` file which exists in more than one of your dependencies

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include NOTICE file 
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file       
}
```